# How to get isolated area using Eagle CAD?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, layout

I've created an area using ratsnest and a simple route as you can see in the first example layout. Both belongs to the VIN net. Then I added a GND polygone.

[image]

Using the ratsnet function I'm expecting to get an isolated VIN area like it is for the VIN route on the left. But the VIN and GND area seems to get merged.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a non-default value to the "rank" parameter for the polygons.

The outer polygon (GND) should have a higher rank (e.g., 2) than the inner polygon (VIN, e.g., 1); this will cause the inner polygon to be subtracted from the outer.

Comment: I just found the 'rank' parameter for the polygone. I think with that I'm getting this done. Not quite sure yet as I just found it.

Comment: Rank should do the trick!